# Plotting known data for server performance

Tags: graph, statistics

I have a CSV file of statistics about the CPU usage for all of my servers with most statistics pre-calculated for me (Thanks SCOM) such as max, min, mean, and standard deviation.

Unfortunately, my high school statistics was a long time ago and I can't remember what kind of graph would be best to use for this sort of data.

```
Name,OperatingSystem,Count,Min,Max,Average,StandardDeviation
server01, Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard,4123.0,0.5674,95.63,3.5469999999999997,3.958
server02, Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard,2675.0,0.5287,96.07,3.016,3.575
server03, Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard,5166.0,0.5915,71.89,20.08,4.7219999999999995
server04, Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard,5112.0,0.5713,91.62,4.102,4.4030000000000005
```

I'm happy to write the python code to plot these out but I'm kind falling down at step one in deciding what kind of graph to use. There are over 200 servers so a single graph might get a little crowded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe grouped box plots? Or just box plots?

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html
[image: grouped box plots using Python seaborn]